# How to get List Name from JS Object Model - List Name from URL problem

Tags: list, javascript, client-object-model, ribbon

I'm trying to connect Ribbon to Pages.. This works, javascript get what I need and pass as parameter to my page.. I pass the URL and the SelectedItemsID..

I'm facing a problem:

If I had a List caller (for example) "List - 1" in URL I find "List%20%201" so there is no trace of the "-"

The response I gave to me is to pass the list name from Javascript as a parameter... How can I get this parameter? My custom action code is this:

```
function enable() {
var items = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems();
var itemCount = CountDictionary(items);
return (itemCount > 0);
}

function CallMe() {
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
this.site = context.get_site();
this.web = context.get_web();
context.load(this.site);
context.load(this.web);
context.executeQueryAsync(
    Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded),
    Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
);    
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {

var items = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems();
var itemCount = CountDictionary(items);

if (itemCount == 0) return;

var ids = "";
for (var i = 0; i < itemCount; i++) {
    ids += items[i].id + ";";
}

//send a request to the zip aspx page.
var form = document.createElement("form");
form.setAttribute("method", "post");
form.setAttribute("action",  this.web.get_serverRelativeUrl() + "/_layouts/deviantpoint.downloadzip/downloadzip.aspx");

var hfSourceUrl = document.createElement("input");
hfSourceUrl.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
hfSourceUrl.setAttribute("name", "sourceUrl");
hfSourceUrl.setAttribute("value", location.href);
form.appendChild(hfSourceUrl);

var hfItemIds = document.createElement("input")
hfItemIds.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
hfItemIds.setAttribute("name", "itemIDs");
hfItemIds.setAttribute("value", ids);
form.appendChild(hfItemIds);

document.body.appendChild(form);
form.submit();
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
this.statusID = SP.UI.Status.addStatus("Download as Zip:", 
    "Failed: " + args.get_message() + " <a href='#' onclick='javascript:closeStatus();return false;'>Close</a>.", true);
SP.UI.Status.setStatusPriColor(this.statusID, "red");
}

function closeStatus() {
 SP.UI.Status.removeStatus(this.statusID);
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I look around and then arrived to this code:

```
function getCurrentListName() {
var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = ctx.get_web();
var currentListGUID = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList();
if (currentListGUID === null) {
    var listname = $(".s4-titletext h2 a:first").html(); //requires JQuery to get list name from ribbon breadcrumb
    return listname;
} else {
return currentListGUID;
}
}
```

It works returning the ID or (if it cannot be found) with the ListName!

Answer (score 11):

You can even use [GetCurrentCtx()](/questions/38532/what-is-the-difference-in-getcurrentctx-and-sp-clientcontext-get-current/38537#38537) to get context info and get much of information among the list title (name):

```
var ctx = GetCurrentCtx();
var title =ctx.ListTitle;
```